# Emailing values selected in a drop down list

Tags: php, jquery

I have a contact form that emails a few input fields but i am struggling to find the right way to check the value from a drop down list.

HTML

```
 <label for="email"><span>E-mail:</span>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" />
</label>


<label for="phone"><span>Tlf:</span>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your number" />
</label>

<label for="service"><span>Service:</span>
<select class="service" id="service">
<option value="choose">Choose</option>
<option value="Option1">Option1</option>
<option value="Option2">Option2</option>
<option value="Option3">Option3</option>
<option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>
</label>
```

PHP

```
 if(!isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userService"]))
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Fields are empty'));
    die($output);
}
```

So am i doing wrong using $_POST for a drop down?

EDIT:

Here is my jquery

```
    var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val(); 
    var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var user_phone      = $('input[name=phone]').val();
```

So i guess what i am missing is this:

```
    var user_service    = $('select[name=service]').val();
```

Comment: No, this is not the complete html. I only added the script that i think are wrong. This works completely without the drop down validation, so something is wrong in my php or id of the drop down.

Comment: you forgot the name attribute!

Comment: For one thing, you're using the wrong POST variables.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your code.

- You don't appear to have `<form></form>` tags in your code/posted question, **add them**; they're not shown in your question, so it's uncertain at this point whether you are using them or not.
- Your form should be `method="post"` including an action. I.e.: `action="handler.php"`
- Your `<select>` is not named.
- You are using the wrong POST variables as compared to your conditional statement:

This is what you are presently using:

```
if(!isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userService"]))
```

Look at this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" />
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your number" />
```

as to how they do not match the conditional statement.

They need to match as per modified conditional statement's variables:

```
if(!isset($_POST["email"]) || !isset($_POST["phone"]) || !isset($_POST["userService"]))
```

while modifying/naming your select as:

```
<select class="service" id="service" name="userService">
```

**N.B.:**

Now, if the rest of your *unshown* PHP code is using the same POST variables, then they would all need to match as to what I've posted here. You will need to do that, because I don't know what the rest of your code looks like.

If the rest of your PHP code is using these POST variables `$_POST["email"]` `$_POST["phone"]` `$_POST["userService"]` then you will need to change your inputs to:

```
<input type="email" name="userEmail" id="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" />
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="userPhone" id="phone" placeholder="Your number" />
```

while keeping your present conditional statement:

```
if(!isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userService"]))
```

---

Having used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have signaled an `Undefined index` warning.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: apart from that, its all good :-)

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake not to post the whole code. My Jquery assigns the right post variables. I will edit my original post to show.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<select>` tag doesn't have a `name` property.

Please modify the code:

```
<label for="service"><span>Service:</span>
<select class="service" id="service" name="userService">
<option value="choose">Choose</option>
<option value="Option1">Option1</option>
<option value="Option2">Option2</option>
<option value="Option3">Option3</option>
<option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>
```